# Why django form post with errors updates instance

Tags: django, validation, django-forms

I have a standard user update form like

```
@login_required()
def personal(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        if user_form.is_valid():
            user = user_form.save()

            update_session_auth_hash(request, user)
            messages.success(request, 'Your personal data has been changed successfully!')

            return redirect('profile')
    else:
        user_form = UserForm(instance=request.user)

    context = {
        'form': user_form,
    }

    return render(request, 'personal.html', context)
```

The problem here is in the line `user_form.is_valid()`. It runs validation logic which collects an error when username is already taken by another user. In this case we have `ValidationError` raised but the `instance` in this form is updated nevertheless due to code in django's `construct_instance` function logic:

```
def construct_instance(form, instance, fields=None, exclude=None):
    """
    Construct and return a model instance from the bound ``form``'s
    ``cleaned_data``, but do not save the returned instance to the database.
    """
    ...
    f.save_form_data(instance, cleaned_data[f.name])
    ...
```

I found this behavior very strange. How can I avoid updating user's instance fields with wrong values if I need, say, display initial user's username on the top of my page?

Comment: Can you add your models.py

Comment: @Olasubomi the standard Django auth.User model

Comment: so basically, the error you are experiencing is that two user can exist at the same time?

Comment: @Olasubomi the problem is BaseForm saves all its fields into User instance even if there is an error in it. It happens when.is_valid() function been called on the form. I wonder why it happens in Django forms. It seems to be unexpected behavior.

Comment: Can you share your template and forms.py so that i can try to reproduce the error at my own end.

Comment: Can you share your template and forms.py so that i can try to reproduce the error at my own end.